# Update Migrations On Visual Studio Community?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I made changes to my identity tables on .net. I need to update stock migrations from this but I don't know how to update for visual studio community expressions. How can I transfer the changes in the tables to the database?
(I'm using mssql.)

Answer (score 0):

Open "Package Manager Console" window, then use below commands to add migration then apply it:

- Add-Migration MigrationName
- Update-Database

For more details see [Migrations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs)